# How can I test if a line is rotating clockwise in relation to another line?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, 2d, line

In the code below, I want to make sure a line is rotating clockwise in relation to another line. The line I want to go clockwise has angle *targetAngle*.

```
var dX = line.start.x - someOtherPoint.x;
var dY = line.start.y - someOtherPoint.y;
var lastAngle = Math.atan2(dY, dX);

var dX = line.start.x - line.end.x;
var dY = line.start.y - line.end.y;
var targetAngle = Math.atan2(dY, dX);

if (targetAngle < lastAngle) {
    // is going counter clockwise
} else {
    // is going clockwise
}
```

This code works in most cases, but breaks when *targetAngle* has gone below 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this:

```
if (targetAngle < lastAngle) {
```

to this:

```
if (targetAngle < lastAngle && !(targetAngle < 0 && lastAngle > 0)) {
```

seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I've only given it a cursory glance, but if it only breaks when targetAngle is below zero, add a check like this:

```
if (targetAngle < 0)
    targetAngle = targetAngle + 360
```

That way you never have to deal with negative angles. Or do something along those lines anyway.

Comment: Or just: `targetAngle = (targetAngle % 2*pi + 2*pi) % 2*pi`, which works for any `targetAngle`, not just values in the interval `[-2*pi, 2*pi]`. Could suffer from some inaccuracy, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in general unless you also know that the difference between two measurements can't be more than 180°. How would you tell the difference between a line rotated counter clockwise 90° vs one rotated clockwise 270° based on the difference between the angles alone? Otherwise, you only need to check the sign of `atan2` - positive for counterclockwise, negative for clockwise (depending on your point of reference).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2

> The atan2 method returns a numeric value between -pi and pi representing the angle theta of an (x,y) point. This is the counterclockwise angle, measured in radians, between the positive X axis, and the point (x,y).